# Jest running individual test passes, but running test suite makes it fail, what could be casuing this?

Tags: jestjs

I'm using Jest for unit testing in a NestJS project. I've been struggling because one of the tests passes when I run it individually but when running the full test suite (which has about 6 tests in total) this sepcific test fails, but the other 5 are fine. I checked twice on the values that are being used in the tested function and I also checked that the conditions are being fulfilled so everything should be working perfectly, but the function isn't returning what it's supposed to.

The data I'm using is mock data and just to make sure I'm not messing it up I copy it into another variable, here is the test I'm running:

```js
it("doesn't apply, 2 consecutive returns are the two first", ()=>{
      const loan = {...mockloan}
      loan.inputRecords[1].paymentAmount = '0'
      loan.schedule[0].status = ScheduleStatus.RETURNED
      loan.inputRecords[2].paymentAmount = '0'
      loan.schedule[1].status = ScheduleStatus.RETURNED
      loan.inputRecords[3].paymentAmount = '218.97'
      loan.schedule[2].status = ScheduleStatus.PENDING
      loan.inputRecords[4].paymentAmount = null
      loan.inputRecords.forEach((i, index )=>{
        console.log(i.paymentID+" -- " + i.paymentAmount + "-- "+ ((index != 0)? (loan.schedule[index-1] ?loan.schedule[index-1].status: ""): ""))
      })
      const {action, reason, returnedInputs} = loanService.appliesForHalfPayment(loan);
      console.log(action)
      expect(action).toBe("collection")
      expect(reason).toBe(LoanTypeEvent.SECOND_RETURN_AFTER_FPD)
      expect(returnedInputs).toBeNull()
})
```

I reviewed the the test suite again and I'm receiving the expected values (in the console.log(action) but the the expect(action).toBe("collection") is receiving null

Comment: When individual test pass but doesnt as a group, my suspicion falls on concurrency.  Do you have any concurrent tests? Does JEST run parallel tests? ANy shared data between your tests? some static/global data?

Comment: @MCLinkTimeError there is no shared data, but I believe I do have concurrent tests. I'm testing the same function inside the test suite and they are syncronous

Comment: does the function use any static/global/shared items? db? maybe the mock is changed? thats what i would aim for. If you could share your tests here it would be easier to give further help

Comment: Nevermind, I don't know what I did to fixed it but now it's working. I'm not able to reproduce this error